Mailto: PHP echo | How to open mailto link in new tab?
How can you open MAILTO link (in PHP echo) in new window?
The Code in a theme:
<?php
global $listing_id;

$listing_id = ( is_null( $listing_id ) ) ? get_the_ID() : $listing_id;

$user_added_by = get_post_meta( $listing_id, 'stm_car_user', true );
$user_fields   = stm_get_user_custom_fields( $user_added_by );
?>
<div class="dealer-contact-unit mail">
    <a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr( $user_fields['email'] ); ?>">
        <div class="email-btn heading-font">
            <?php echo wp_kses( $de_icon, apply_filters( 'stm_ew_kses_svg', array() ) ); ?> 
            <span>
                <?php echo esc_html( $de_label ); ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

My attempts.
I put target="_blank" as follows:
<a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr( $user_fields['email'] ); ?>" target="_blank">

or like:
<a target="_blank" href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr( $user_fields['email'] ); ?>">

In both cases a new tab does not open.
Supplement information
Difference between the theme code above and the code of the answer:
I always cashed after every change in the code. After caching the following result:
The theme code:
1.a) Chrome:  (Perfect)

Logged-in members can write themselves an email. A new webmail client
tab opens
Logged-in members can write an email to an other member. A new
webmail client tab opens
Visitors can write an email. A new webmail client tab opens

1.b) Firefox:

Logged-in members can write themselves an email. The website tab is
used for this
Logged-in members can wrrte an email to an other member. The website
tab is used for this
Visitors can write an email. The website tab is used for this

It's Firefox that does not open a new tab for the webmail client. If you press CTRL + link a new tab opens for the webmail client. But how you do it with only one click?
Code of the answer:
2.) Chrome + Firefox:

Logged-in members cannot write themselves an email
Logged-in members cannot write an email to an other member (bad)
Visitors can write an email. A new webmail client tab opens

What I prefer:
case 1.a)  But also for Firefox.  I don't know yet why Firefox  does not open a new tab for the webmail client
I would also be satisfied:
case 2.)  But logged-in members must be able to write an email to an other member in a new tab opened

mailto: will open the default mail client on the machine. That might be a desktop app, or it might be a web interface potentially (e.g. gmail, yahoo mail, or something). It depends how the user's machine is configured. I don't think "open in a new tab" really makes much sense in that context. When you say the new tab does not open, are you saying that nothing happens at all? Or do you mean it navigates to a webmail  interface within the current tab? It wasn't clear.

"mailto: will open the default mail client on the machine".  Yes, correct. It navigates to a webmail interface within the current tab where you can choose your email app (e.g. gmail, yahoo mail etc..). This can be in the same tab. It is just a small pop-up window you know. But when you now click on a specific email app the webmail interface takes now the current tab and your origin website disappears in favor of this email app interface (e.g. gmail, yahoo mail etc..). Of course, I prefer that a new tab is opened for the email app interface when the client clicks on his desired email app.

re your last update: There's nothing in the code you've provided which would seem to affect what's rendered in the browser depending on if a user is logged into your application or not. And once that code is in the browser, the browser itself does not really know or care if the user is logged into your backend or not. So it's hard to see how this could be affecting it - unless in fact you do render different content somehow for logged-in and not-logged in users, which isn't shown here. Are you 100% certain that what you've given us here is actually a [mre] of this issue, now?

Good point. I just assume that different content somehow is rendered for logged in and unlogged users. In this spirit, it is not "my" code but the code of a theme. I have changed the wording. I cannot say anything more from a programming point of view because I do not know enough about the nesting in the theme code. You're right. I would even be interested to know what's rendered in the browser depending on if a user is logged into the application or not.

I just assume...why do you assume? It's programming...it's deterministic...and you can inspect everything. There's no need to assume anything. Go and look in your browser's developer tools and see what's actually rendered in the browser in each different case, for the email link.

it is not "my" code but the code of a theme...ah ok. You never mentioned this before. If you have an issue with a theme you should always reach out to the maintainer of the theme first of all. We expected that this was your own code you were asking about, and that you therefore understood it reasonably well and are free to change it. If you modify the theme's code yourself too much it would make it much more difficult to get future updates to the theme and use them without problems.

I hope I was able to give you all the reputation benefits per click...I haven't done anything, such as write an answer, which would gain me reputation points. Points aren't given for upvoting a comment. I was hoping we could get to the point where the problem was clear enough to write another answer.

In principle, the problem is solved...really? I thought it was still an issue for logged-in users?

@ADyson
You are absolutely right. Files are overwritten with an update. The PHP file is inside a plugin. And this plugin is updated from time to time. Then everything is overwritten. I have a child theme. It is in the "themes" folder. But that is not relevant here because the plugins are in the "plugins" folder. Q:  How can I make a change in a PHP file which is part of a plugin without the content of this file being overwritten during an update ?   (Proposal: changing the cmd value 755, 644 etc.. I need to check which is relevant in my case)

Try this
working example from jsfiddle
replace the <div class="dealer-contact-unit mail">....<a href ..... </a></div> with the HTML/PHP below
<div class="dealer-contact-unit mail" data-href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr( $user_fields['email'] ); ?>">
  <div class="email-btn heading-font">
    <?php echo wp_kses( $de_icon, apply_filters( 'stm_ew_kses_svg', array() ) ); ?>
    <span>
      <?php echo esc_html( $de_label ); ?>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

Then add somewhere on the page this - OUTSIDE the <?PHP ... ?> tags
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
  document.querySelector('.mail').addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    const email = e.target.closest('div.mail').dataset.href;
    window.open(email,'_blank');
    // or 
    // location.href=email; 
  });
});
</script>


Your first code block is JavaScript. I only know that you can put JS in a PHP file.
My code above is a PHP file. So I put your first code block within the PHP tags.
And your second code block after the PHP closing tag.
I'm sorry it doesn't work.
"Critical error" is the result and the website changes appearance.

@vallespir So I put your first code block within the PHP tags...why? You said yourself that it's JavaScript. So put it in a <script> block, as you normally do with JavaScript. Since it's not PHP, the PHP interpreter will not be able to understand it, and that would explain why you got an error when you tried that.

@vallespir I only know that you can put JS in a PHP file...only in the same way that you can put HTML in a "PHP file" too. The bits in a PHP file which are within the PHP tags are executed as PHP code. The rest of the content is just sent to the browser as-is. Since JavaScript isn't PHP, and it's designed to be executed by the brower, then it belongs with the "rest of the content", i.e. outside the PHP tags. The browser will then receive it and execute it. (Any anyway, even if PHP could run this, running it server-side would make no sense since it's listening for a browser click event!!)

@ADyson + mplungjan |
Thank you. I understand what to do.  First code block in script tags  outside of the PHP tags.
With the given code now the mouse pointer does not allow clicking on the message box field on the web site. I can't open the popup window for the default mail client.
I found out there is "data-href" in your code, but not the obligatory:   This is a problem. "data-href" does not allow the clicking.

@vallespir the href isn't needed, precisely because the JS handles the clicking on the element with the mail CSS class (it will match to <div class="dealer-contact-unit mail").

@vallespir The code mplungjan has provided will work - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ADyson82/vxsy807e/ . If it's not working for you, do something like check your browser's console for errors, use the JS debugger in the browser to see what's happening, and so on.

Indeed it does work. Here is an example with the PHP substituted for action email address and text: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xy3m479q/ - I even added some CSS to make the cursor look like a pointer

Just an update.  For the moment I can't identify the issue.  I added Mouse pointer with your CSS. If I click on the message box field  nothing happens. The pop-up window of webmail interface  does not open.
I checked everything twice, tripple.
And if I insert the given   it opens but not in a new tab.
Debugger:  There is no error.  No red exclamation mark.
Yes, in your app jsfiddle the code works like a charm.
I need a break and don't know what to do next.

@vallespir As I said earlier, if something is not working for you in JavaScript/HTML then do something like check your browser's console for errors, use the JS debugger in the browser to see what's happening, check the element inspector to ensure the HTML was rendered as expected, and so on. If you need more help, update your question with a [mre] of this scenario so we can see for ourselves.

If you right-click and inspect the web page, does the script and div look like in my fiddle (with your emails and text of course)? Did you wrap the script in script tags?

@mplungjan   Exactly that.  Your both code blocks are correctly implemented.

BTW,  I want to write a comment with structure. Is that possible here.   Has this comment text box HTML features?

@vallespir you can use some basic markdown in the comments, like backticks (e.g. this is in backticks).  But that's all . There is no line formatting, etc. Comments should only include the very briefest of code examples, as part of clarifying the situation quickly. If you need to add a more comprehensive example then, as I said earlier in this thread, you must edit your question.

@ADyson   Thanks for your hint. I added more content in my origin question.  If you read it you see that the Firefox Debugger/Console states:
"Warning: "4 cookies use the recommended "SameSite" attribute incorrectly"
I deleted ALL cookies + cache on my PC. That was the deal!!
But I don't know yet if these 4 cookies are related to it.  I don't think so !  I think other cookies OR the cache are responsible for the "not opening tab".

@vallespir Did you look at what those cookies were before you deleted them?

@ADyson  Everything is working very well at the moment. Now when I use the Firefox debugger again, the message appears again:
"Some cookies use the recommended "SameSite" attribute incorrectly"
However, the functionality is still there: The webmail client opens in a new tab!  Great.
So it must have been other cookies or the cache?!? The cache ?!
However, I'll look into what this "SameSite" means and will comment.

@vallespir I do not think it is related to cookies, but great to hear it works. Please visit this help page
